# BIOS modules and what are they

Tags: boot, bios, uefi, gpt, flashing

Computer : Lenovo G560 model 20042
CPU : Intel Pentium P2600
Northbridge : Intel PM55
Southbridge : Intel HM55
CMOS RAM : 512 bytes
BIOS chip or size: unknown

I backed up my BIOS using the official flashing utility by changing the values in the parameters file, and am currently trying make sense of it in the Insyde H2OEZE editor (obtained [here](http://www.mediafire.com/file/0zg6966v21hkw36/EzH2O.zip)). The most powerful in it seems the module replacer/inserter/deleter, but I don't know what to do exactly. I know that the modules are like apps, like CSM in UEFI, but the delete menu shows a series of GUID or something, which is not helpful. My antepenultimate goal (yes, I checked that is a word) is to switch the laptop over to UEFI (it is out of warranty), my penultimate goal being to switch the hard disk over to GPT, with the ultimate goal being to install Windows 64-bit on a 6th partition and transfer stuff till it is OK to delete the 32-bit partition.

So, how to obtain modules? Are they machine specific or do they need to be built? Can I do some TianoCore magic to switch it over to UEFI or make it UEFI compatible?